# recursive method in ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, methods

```
def append(arr, n)  
    return arr if n < 0 
    puts "n1: #{n}, #{arr}"
    append(arr, n-1)
    puts "n2: #{n}, #{arr}"
    arr << n
    puts "n3: #{n}, #{arr}"
    arr
end 

append([],4) #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I can't seem to understand this recursive method. It produces an array from 0 up to n.

I added a few puts to see how the arr and n acted.

```
n1: 4, []
n1: 3, []
n1: 2, []
n1: 1, []
n1: 0, []
n2: 0, []
n3: 0, [0]
n2: 1, [0]
n3: 1, [0, 1]
n2: 2, [0, 1]
n3: 2, [0, 1, 2]
n2: 3, [0, 1, 2]
n3: 3, [0, 1, 2, 3]
n2: 4, [0, 1, 2, 3]
n3: 4, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I understand how n counts down to -1, and then the arr is returned. What is confusing me is where the counting up occurs. It seems to me that when `append(arr, -1)` is called, the arr is returned and the loop will stop and all I get is []. So why does the method continues to run after the return is called? And where does the counting up occur?

Comment: What's `reverse_append`?

Comment: sorry, typo. i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` returns from the current method, not from all recursive calls. That said, after first `return` the control flow goes to the line, next to call to `append`. For the `n=2` the backtrace will be as follows:

```
main ⇒ append                     # n = 2
main ⇒ append ⇒ append            # n = 1
main ⇒ append ⇒ append ⇒ append   # n = 0, return to:
main ⇒ append ⇒ append            # here n = 1, continue execution till end
main ⇒ append                     # here n = 2, continue execution till end
main                              # the topmost recursion level returned to main
```